# Unit Testing Web Services using .net

Tags: wcf, web-services, load-testing

I have wcf .net client to a webservice.  I am trying to ensure that the connection to this web service is solid and that the web-service itself is sturdy and can stand up and take a pounding.  I was hoping to hit it with 50 different asynchronous calls to ensure that it is working well.  Is there a way that I can use the .net framework to make multiple asynchronous calls to the webservice?

Comment: Can't you use your testing framework and write a "unit" test that utilizes [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992198.aspx) to do multiple calls? All the popular testing frameworks are supported through (amongst others) extensions in VS2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using VS 2012 you can use the [built-in load testing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/06/04/getting-started-with-load-testing-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

You can also use free tools such as [LoadUI](http://www.loadui.org/)

Comment: So nothing in vs2010 to do a little load testing huh?  Alright.  LoadUI it is.

Comment: Actually 2010 has a featurepack for load testing but I've not used it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff520697.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 (Test edition or Ultimate edition) has excellent support for performance and load testing (with plenty of extensibility points to meet your needs). Check the following blog for a series of links related to load and web performance testing:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edglas/archive/2007/12/17/content-index-for-web-tests-and-load-tests.aspx

A good approach is to use fiddler to record traffic between application and service and then export this into a web performance test.